# How can I save favourite locations in a large Word Doc?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working with a very large technical document and there are a few sections I keep needing to jump between. I can do it from the index but even this is annoying. Is there a way to set favourites/bookmarks that are personal to me? I know Word supports "bookmarks" but these are actually inserted into the document as I understand it more like a reference.

What is the best way to achieve what I want, so I can see a list of my favourite locations and jump between them really quickly?

Comment: If your doc is using Headers, you can open the review panel and jump to the section you want. Additionally,  I often use split screen when I need to work in two places at once.

Answer (score 0):

Hit `CTRL+SHIFT+F5` to open up the bookmarks menu, then name and save a bookmark.

At any time, hit `CTRL+G` to open the find and replace dialog box, and the 3rd tab "Go To" has Bookmarks.

Alternatively, you can use the "bookmark" button in the "Insert" ribbon under "Links".